# action-cable-testing with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, channel, actioncable

My Ruby on Rails application is working as desired. Things are getting broadcast and received as I want. However, I want to add unit testing to channels using `action-cable-testing` gem. My user registration is done using `Devise`. 
Here is my `connection.rb` file:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private
    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have a `message_notifications_channel.rb` like this:

```
class MessageNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "some_channel"
    if current_user&.account_id
      stream_from "message_notifications_channel_#{current_user.account_id}"
    end
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

This channel allows a user, when signed in, to stream from `message_notifications_channel_accountID` where accountID is id of the account to which the user belongs.

My `cable.js` file is the same as shown in the ruby guide:

```
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the `rails generate channel` command.
//
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

I'm having trouble with the following rspec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MessageNotificationsChannel, type: :channel do
  let(:authorized_senders) {['11111']}
  let(:common_user_phone){'17777777777'}
  let(:account) {FactoryGirl.create(:account, authorized_senders: authorized_senders)}
  let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user, account: account, admin: true)}
  context 'when user is authenticated' do
    describe '#connect' do
      it 'accepts connection' do
        sign_in user
        subscribe(account_id: user.account_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error I got is: 
Failure/Error: if current_user&.account_id

```
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<MessageNotificationsChannel:0x000000000721d890>
```

The location of the error is in my `message_notifications_channel.rb` file. I put a `byebug` before `self.current_user = find_verified_user` in the `connect` method in `connection.rb`, the test would not hit that byebug at all. And no surprise, I would get that error later.

When I'm running in development environment that byebug will get hit and things will run normally.

This is my `cable.yml`:

```
redis: &redis
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

production: *redis
development: *redis
test:
 *redis
```

I've looked at https://github.com/palkan/action-cable-testing/issues/26#issuecomment-392481619 
That person's code does not really use Devise. It's crucial that all parts of my app uses devise for user authentication.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "**stub_connection current_user: users(:some_user_from_fixtures)**" to your test. So for your code it would be:

```
   it 'accepts connection' do
        sign_in user
        stub_connection current_user: user
        subscribe(account_id: user.account_id)
   end
```

This should work. For more information visit rails official documentation: [Testing Action Cable](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#channel-test-case)